# Avoid resetting data set when knitting R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I need to create a data set using rnorm function and work with it. However, whenever I try to knit my document, the rnorm function automatically runs again and resets the previous data I worked with. Is there anyway that I can retain the data set once created even after knitting?

Comment: The concept of the r-markdown document is to run off a fresh environment, so any usage of functions relying on randomization will do this. You can use `set.seed()` to get the same results appear each time you knit.

Comment: I think that's the think I'm searching for, Phil. Do you mind teaching me how to use this set.seed code? the Help section was too confusing and I got kinda lost...

Comment: If you add a line on the early part of your script, something like `set.seed(1)`, functions that rely on randomization will provide the same results each time you run them.